# Anime involving a love story and two samurai/assassin villages, previously on unfriendly terms, that were made to fight each other again

Tags: basilisk

Please help me find the name of this anime I've watched online maybe 3 years ago. This is how I remember it:

There were two villages with previously unfriendly assassins or samurais (possibly with supernatural powers) that made some sort of pact because a woman from one village and a man from the other were in love. They were always meeting somewhere in the middle of the path between the villages. It was almost sunrise and each wanted to stay together a little bit longer.

In the meantime, some weird bad person decided the villages had to have a tournament of some sort, and scrolls were given to the heads of the families. They had a fight, maybe both died? And a crow or some bird took one of the scrolls. The Romeo/Juliet (not their real names) parted ways. Maybe some spiderwebs now and maybe the scrolls were 10 for each of the strongest warriors.

And there was fighting. In the last episode, the only ones left were the Romeo/Juliet combo. I think the Juliet was seriously injured and one of them was blind. Furthermore, one of them took some kind of poison. They probably both died at the end, but I think the weird bad person died, too, maybe in a carriage carried by people, not horses.

I'm not sure about most of the stuff, except for the title of my request. :? If anyone can help me, I'll be happy to watch this anime again. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a lot like [Basilisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilisk_%28manga%29).

[image]

There are two warring ninja clans, one led by a girl, Oboro Iga, and the other a man, Gennosuke Kouga, who are both secretly in love with each other. They all have unique supernatural powers. During the course of the story, Gennosuke is blinded by a spell of some sort and they both of to fight each other at the end of the series.

It's very much like a "Romeo/Juliet" type story set in 17th century Japan.

More info:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilisk_%28manga%29)
- [Wikia](http://basilisk.wikia.com/wiki/Basilisk_%28anime%29)
- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=4318)
- [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime/67/Basilisk:_Kouga_Ninpou_Chou)

Comment: wow that was super fast and the one I was looking for :)

Comment: @poli89. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215106). This way, other people will know the question's been answered. As a nice bonus, you even get + 2 rep ;)